# Passing database user name and password through a form, for database Connection in Flask App

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask app, which connects to a DB2 database and gets data from the database but only when users enter their DB2 database username and password through a form. I am using WTF element in database connection login form (app also has an app user login), below is what I am trying to do, I have placed all the database connections parameters inside a route

```
class DBForm(FlaskForm):
DBuser = StringField('DB.Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(1, 20)])
DBpass = PasswordField('DB.Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
remember_me = BooleanField('Remember me')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home():
    form = DBForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        USER_ID = form.DBuser.data 
        USER_PASS = form.DBpass.data
        conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=WDLAB; HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1; PORT=10000; PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=USER_ID;PWD=USER_PASS;", "", "")
        cur = db2.conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('select * from JOB_ROLE')
        data = cur.fetchall()        
        return render_template('index.html',form=form,data=data)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
    conn.close()
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
                {{form.csrf_token }}
                {{form.DBuser.label }}
                {{form.DBuser }}
                {{form.DBpass.label }}
                {{form.DBpass }}
                {{form.remember_me }}

                <button type="submit">Connect</button>
            </div>
```

this passes connection parameters to database, but fails to connect with an **Incorrect User Name and Password** Error, I was thinking if this error was because the username and password by this method is not passed within single quotes in `conn`, tried to concatenate quotes when I pass it to `conn` but that as well gives same outcome. request expert help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to substitute the username and password in your DSN with the form data:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=WDLAB; HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1; PORT=10000; PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={};PWD={};".format(USER_ID, USER_PASS), "", "")
```